# Time difference getting different result

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using the following query :

```
SELECT
        concat(
            extract(day from ('2023-02-27 15:09:00'::timestamp - '2022-06-09 15:39:00'::timestamp)),' days ',
            extract(hour from ('2023-02-27 15:09:00'::timestamp - '2022-06-09 15:39:00'::timestamp)),' hours ',
            extract(minute from ('2023-02-27 15:09:00'::timestamp - '2022-06-09 15:39:00'::timestamp)),' minutes ',
            extract(second from ('2023-02-27 15:09:00'::timestamp - '2022-06-09 15:39:00'::timestamp)),' seconds'
        ) as duration,
        justify_interval(make_interval(secs =>22725019)) AS "duration 2"
```

Output :

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
| duration                                      | duration 2                                       |    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                 
| 262 days 23 hours 30 minutes 0.000000 seconds | {"months":8,"days":23,"minutes":30,"seconds":19} |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

On this website I have the following result (https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=09&m1=06&y1=2022&d2=27&m2=02&y2=2023&h1=15&i1=39&s1=00&h2=15&i2=09&s2=00):

```
262 days, 23 hours, 30 minutes and 0 seconds
8 months, 17 days, 23 hours, 30 minutes
```

Demo : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7aYekUESoZwv6DJv77VaCW/0

Why do I have different result ?

**EDIT :**

`22725019` is the result of

```
((1677506971778 - 1654781952676) / 1000)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `justify_interval()` on the result of the difference:

```
justify_interval('2023-02-27 15:09:00'::timestamp - '2022-06-09 15:39:00'::timestamp)
```